# Implement custom metrics in Keras without using callbacks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My question is simple and yet I have struggled to find a clear working answer with no success.

I want to calculate my own metrics on the test(validation) data and for that I need to know the `y_pred` for the `model.evaluate` call that was executed at the end of the epoch. With a Keras callback instance I can have to call

```
model.predict
```

at the end of the epoch which can be an additional overhead considering that it must has been for sure once calculated before for the `model.evaluate` call.

So my question is, is the value of `y_pred` after evaluation accessible and if so how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the value of y_pred after evaluation accessible ?

No, the reason being `on_epoch_end` is [called at the end of an epoch during training](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/), so predictions on validation set will not be available.

There are different ways to implement custom metrics. Hope this is what you are looking for: (Without using callback)

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def f1_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average="macro")
    return f1


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['acc', f1_macro])
```

This will evaluate on both the metrics - accuracy & f1_macro

Replace `f1_macro` function with your own custom metrics function, but make sure it takes `y_true` & `y_pred` as input parameters.

Comment: what I understand is, this custom metric function will be called after each batch for training and evaluation, am I right ? and if I just made sure that the function takes y_true and y_pred as input parameters, does this mean that the y_true and y_pred will be automatically passed to the custom metric function whenever it is called ?

Comment: all metrics given to the `metrics` argument will be called during the validation stage and yes, `y_true` & `y_pred ` will be automatically passed as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, y_true and y_pred are supposed to be the same length as a batch size, am I right ?

Comment: yes, 1st dimension will be equal to batch or input samples. 2nd dimension will be equal to number of dense units in output layer.

Comment: I have tried this exact metric but it's giving me this error: OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.